# How to access the previous row from the database

Tags: django

views.py

```
            AppTruepower = form.cleaned_data['truepower_reading']
            AppApparent = form.cleaned_data['apparentpower_reading']
            AppVoltage = form.cleaned_data['voltage_reading']
            AppDate = form.cleaned_data['Date']
            AppTime = form.cleaned_data['Time']
            prevdate=KEBReading.objects.latest("id")
            print prevdate.truepower_reading
            print id
            KEBReading.objects.filter(id=id).update(truepower_reading=AppTruepower,apparentpower_reading=AppApparent,
                                                        voltage_reading=AppVoltage,datetime_reading=datetime.combine(AppDate,AppTime))


            a=KEBReading.objects.filter(id=id).values("truepower_reading")
            print a
            b=KEBReading.objects.filter(id=id).values("apparentpower_reading")
            print b
            print prevdate.truepower_reading
```

when editing a row in django forms. i need to access the previous row to do some   calculation. could sumbody suggest me how can i get the previous row. if i use   model.s.object.latest() i get the last row entered,but in my case i need to get the previous    row i.e previuos row of the current row im going to edit.

Comment: you mean the last one? you can use "order_by"

Comment: ya the previous row to the row im gonna edit. for example, if im editing row number=10 i need to access the row number 9.

Answer (score 0):

I depends upon what order you mean for the rows. If you want previous row by `id` you can do

```
curr_row = KEBReading.objects.filter(id=current_id)
#decrement id until you find valid record, as previous id might have deleted.
prev_row = KEBReading.objects.filter(id=current_id-1)
```

If you want order by some other field then

```
rows = KEBReading.objects.order_by('-some_field_to_order') # use - for reverse ordering
current_row = rows[0]
prev_row = rows[1]  
#verify for index errors though.
```

Comment: previous id is not always -1 from the current!

Comment: @UnLiMiTeD, True, added a note to find last available.

Comment: Why not just use the second method for all cases?

Comment: rows = KEBReading.objects.filter(id__lte=current_id).order_by('-id')[0:2]
current_row, previous_row = rows